# SQL split string at first occurance of a number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I hava a field in my database containing street and housenumber. I want to split the housenumber in a new column. Can I do this by someting like

```
INSERT INTO mytable(housenumber) VALUES SELECT ??? FROM mytable ?
```

Comment: What about my address - 1, Building A, Street, Town - (and there is a building B and I just had a web form offering me two flat 1s to choose from) where do you want the building to go?

Comment: How is your field formatted, do you have a comma or something else between street and house number?

Comment: my db only contains addresses in german format, means <street> <housenumber>

Comment: I suspect that you still may encounter some streets where the number will be the part of the street, and will not be at the beginning, but I just cannot find the examples. I thought about names of kings, but usually Roman numbers are used there, so there is no problem. In any case you will need just to find another regexp.

Comment: "Straße des 17. Juni", a popular street in the center of Berlin. Watch out for those.

Comment: Also in the city of Manheim you have street names like "B 1, 1-2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution seems to use [substring function with regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-string.html). I hope your version of PostgreSQL supports them.

```sql
SELECT adres,
       substring(adres from '^.*?(?=[0-9]|$)') AS street,
       substring(adres from '[0-9].*$') AS housenum
  FROM mytable;
```

```
      adres      |  street   |    housenum
-----------------+--------------+-----------------
 some string 12  | some string  | 12
 another 2c      | another      | 2c
 no number       | no number    | 
 99 first number |              | 99 first number
 withnumber1 234 | withnumber   | 1 234
(5 rows)
```

As *NullUserException* mentioned in the comment, the **street name may contain a number itself**, which should not be considered a house number. In this case I suppose that a "house number" may be defined as the substring starting with a digit, preceded by a space.

The regular expressions would in this case look this way:

```sql
SELECT adres,
       substring(adres from '^.*?(?=\\s[0-9]|$)') AS street,
       substring(adres from '\\s([0-9].*)$') AS housenum
  FROM mytable;
```

The examples will be then split differently:

```
      adres      |    street       | housenum
-----------------+-----------------+-----------
 some string 12  | some string     | 12
 another 2c      | another         | 2c
 no number       | no number       | 
 99 first number | 99 first number | 
 withnumber1 234 | withnumber1     | 234
(5 rows)
```

Comment: What if the street contains a number?

Comment: Then the problem must be defined differently. I would say "split on a first number directly after some whitespace". Let's see whether I can cook some regexp for this.. ;-)